# Python issue with input

Tags: python, python-3.x

**My code Im working in is in python, and i trying to input a double true, and get a number output

def get_Alarm(prompt):

```
TT=0.95
```

TF=0.94

FT=0.29

FF=0.001
    while True:

try:
            return

{"True,True":TT,"True,False":TF,"False,True":FT,"False,False":FF}[input(prompt).lower()]

```
        return
```

{"true,true":TT,"true,false":TF,"false,true":FT,"false,false":FF}[input(prompt).lower()]

except KeyError:

print("Invalid input please enter true and, or False!")**

def get_EarthQ(prompt):

a=0.002

b=0.998

while True:

try:
            return {"true": a, "false": b}[input(prompt).lower()]

return {"True": a, "False": b}[input(prompt).lower()]

except KeyError:

print("Invalid input please enter True or False!")

def get_Burg(prompt):

```
a=0.001
```

b=0.999

while True:

try:

return {"true": a, "false": b}[input(prompt).lower()]

return {"True": a, "False": b}[input(prompt).lower()]

except KeyError:
            print("Invalid input please enter True or False!")

print("Alarm system")

print(get_Burg("Is probability burlar intruding home?"))

print(get_EarthQ("Did you have an earthquake answer True or False?"))

print("What is the probability of the alarm going off from either burgerly or earthquake or both")

print(get_Alarm("Add true, true for example to the get the probability, Enter?"))

I get stuck in a loop when I add a true,true for getAlarm(prompt)
I wanted to know what Im doing wrong

Comment: You might want to clean up your code example here. This is unreadable

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your code? It's almost impossible to tell what's going on with the code in its current state. If you can't figure out how to use the Stack Overflow editor, just paste the code from your machine into your question & we'll fix it for you, but we need the indentation to be correct.

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code.  The easiest way to do that would be delete your code and copy it back in fresh.  Then highlight the code and press the `{}` symbol at the top of the question editor.  That adds an additional four spaces in front of each line making the lines display as code.

Comment: If I guess at your indentation and look at `getAlarm()`, I can see that this line `return {"True,True":TT,"True,False":TF,"False,True":FT,"False,False":FF}[input(prompt).lower()]` will always throw a `KeyError` because the input is lowercased, but the keys always contain uppercase characters.  Since this bit of code is in a try-except inside an infinite while loop it will keep on looping no matter what the input is.

Comment: Your `try` statement includes `return` twice

Comment: I'm going to vote to close your question as you have not responded to requests to edit your question.  StackOverflow is a great place to get help, but it's good to know some basics about asking questions before posting another.  I encourage you to read the Asking section of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I have edited it for him

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `try` statements here, they as for another `input` and never exits the `while True:` loop, you need a way to exit that `while True:` loop

```
def get_Alarm(prompt):
    TT=0.95
    TF=0.94
    FT=0.29
    FF=0.001
    while True:
        try:
            return {"True,True":TT,"True,False":TF,"False,True":FT,"False,False":FF}[input(prompt).lower()]

            return {"true,true":TT,"true,false":TF,"false,true":FT,"false,false":FF}[input(prompt).lower()]

        except KeyError:
            print("Invalid input please enter true and, or False!")
```

Also note once the first `return` exectutes that second `return` will not be accessed